# Hilt - How can I inject dependencies into adapter?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am providing dependency in module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideImageUtil(@ImageUrl imageUrl: String): ImageUtil = GlideImageUtil(imageUrl)
```

I am trying to inject it into RecyclerView adapter:

```
class MainAdapter(private val goods: ArrayList<GoodItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {

    @Inject
    lateinit private var imageUtil: ImageUtil
```

I used to inject this way using Dagger:

```
object Injector {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    fun initAppComponent(context: Context){

        if(context is Activity){
            throw IllegalStateException("pass an Application as an argument to avoid memory leaks")
        }

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(context))
                .build()

    }

}
```

In adapter:

```
init {
    Injector.appComponent.inject(this)
}
```

How can I inject dependency into the adapter using Hilt? As I understood now "appComponent" is generated by Hilt. How can I access it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First create EntryPoint in your custom class

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface MyEntryPoint {
    fun getImageUtil(): ImageUtil
}
```

It is simple interface with `@EntryPoint` annotation. Since your dependency (ImageUtil) is singleton you should use `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` annotation to declare component. Finally declare a method to get your dependency `fun getImageUtil(): ImageUtil`

You can get your dependency in init block of your Adapter

```
init {
    val myEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, MyEntryPoint::class.java)
    imageUtil = myEntryPoint.getImageUtil()
}
```

Full code

```
class MainAdapter(
    context: Context,
    private val goods: ArrayList<GoodItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {

    var imageUtil: ImageUtil

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface MyEntryPoint {
        fun getImageUtil(): ImageUtil
    }

    init {
        val myEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, MyEntryPoint::class.java)
        imageUtil = myEntryPoint.getImageUtil()
    }
}
```

See also https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported

Comment: it looks confusing.

Comment: it is much better explanation than official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Assisted Injection with Dagger 2 which allows you to pass in types that might not be available initially and needs to be passed later. https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add an [`@AndroidEntryPoint`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point.html) and likely will have to [inject the constructor](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#define-bindings),
because the `imageUrl` needs to come from somewhere; for example from Gradle:

```
javaCompileOptions {
  annotationProcessorOptions {
    arguments += ["imageUrl": "..."]
  }
}
```

And I think `@Singleton @Provides` / `@Singleton @Binds` annotations do require a scope.

Comment: I think you can not add @AndroidEntryPoint into an adapter class

Comment: @AndroidEntyPoint only is fragment, activity, view, service, and broadcast Receiver